# Saving many-to-many relationship through intermediate model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content     = HTMLField()
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    authors     = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

When I create a post like this:

```
x = Post(title="blah", content="blah)
```

How can I add multiple authors to this Post? The authors model is created as an intermediate model and I have not defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to save the model instance before adding any many to many relationships [(refer documentation)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
 x.save()
```

To add multiple users, loop it through the user's queryset.

```
users = User.objects.filter(foo=bars)
for item in users:
    x.authors.add(item)
```

Comment: Should you not save the model after adding all the authors?

Comment: No, you don't need to call save() after adding the authors. As add() is mapping and saving the relationship.